# Is there a Java function which parses escaped characters?

Tags: java, string

I'm looking for a built-in Java functions which for example can convert `"\\n"` into `"\n"`.

Something like this:

```
assert parseFunc("\\n") = "\n"
```

Or do I have to manually search-and-replace all the escaped characters?

Comment: DO you mean you want to replace \\n with a newline character?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use `StringEscapeUtils.unescapeJava(s)` from [Apache Commons Lang](http://commons.apache.org/lang). It works for all escape sequences, including Unicode characters (i.e. `\u1234`).

https://commons.apache.org/lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringEscapeUtils.html#unescapeJava-java.lang.String-

Comment: This is what i was looking for! Had trouble with unicode escaped characters from php's json_encode

Answer (score 5):

Anthony is 99% right -- since backslash is also a reserved character in regular expressions, it needs to be escaped a second time:

```
result = myString.replaceAll("\\\\n", "\n");
```

Answer (score 1):

Just use the strings own replaceAll method.

```
result = myString.replaceAll("\\n", "\n");
```

However if you want match all escape sequences then you could use a Matcher.  See http://www.regular-expressions.info/java.html for a very basic example of using Matcher.

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\(.)");
Matcher m = p.matcher("This is tab \\t and \\n this is on a new line");
StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
while (m.find()) {
   String s = m.group(1);
   if (s == "n") {s = "\n"; }
   else if (s == "t") {s = "\t"; } 
   m.appendReplacement(sb, s);
}
m.appendTail(sb);
System.out.println(sb.toString());
```

You just need to make the assignment to s more sophisticated depending on the number and type of escapes you want to handle.  (Warning this is air code, I'm not Java developer)

Comment: Won't that be a performance drain if I do a replaceAll for every escapable character, i.e. 8 times? (http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/java/data/characters.html)

Comment: Sorry I was just showing an anwser to your simple case (its a knee-jerk that many of us do it doesn't really answer your question).  Thats why I point you at the Matcher class, which in combination with a StringBuffer you can create a result string in one pass.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to list all possible escaped characters you can delegate this to Properties behaviour

```
    String escapedText="This is tab \\t and \\rthis is on a new line";
    Properties prop = new Properties();     
    prop.load(new StringReader("x=" + escapedText + "\n"));
    String decoded = prop.getProperty("x");
    System.out.println(decoded);
```

This handle all possible characters