# How to transform strings representing 'special' characters to their character representation

Tags: java, string, char

I want to turn two-character strings representing special non-printing characters, such as "\t","\n","\a",... into their single character representations. Is there any general way to do it (with general, I mean an alternative to explicitly translating each string into each character)?

Ideal behavior (my strings are being read from a file. This is just an example):

```java
String str = "\\t";
char c = toChar(str); // c now represents the tab character '\t'
```

Comment: Have you taken a look at this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1327355/is-there-a-java-function-which-parses-escaped-characters)?  It seems to cover your case with an Apache Commons method, if you are able to use that. Just realized that question is really old though, so maybe out of date.

Comment: @Nexevis The Answers on [that Question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1327355/642706) are outdated. None use the new functionality built into Java 15+. See [my Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77019207/642706) here for details.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### tl;dr

In Java 15+:

```
    ( "\\" + "t" ).translateEscapes()  -->  TAB character
    ( "\\" + "n" ).translateEscapes()  -->  LINE FEED character
    ( "\\" + "s" ).translateEscapes()  -->  SPACE character
    …
```

### `String#translateEscapes`

In Java 15+, use [`String#translateEscapes`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html#translateEscapes()) method.

The `char` type has been essentially broken since Java 2, legacy since Java 5. Make a habit of using [code point](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_point) integers and `String` objects instead.

```java
final String input = "\\" + "t";
final String TAB = input.translateEscapes ( );
```

Dump to console. Use code points to inspect actual contents of each string.

```java
System.out.println ( "input = " + input );
System.out.println ( "input code points = " + Arrays.toString ( input.codePoints ( ).toArray ( ) ) );
System.out.println ( "TAB code points = " + Arrays.toString ( TAB.codePoints ( ).toArray ( ) ) );
```

When run, we verify that we indeed began with a two-character string, a back-slash and a "t". After our call, we transformed that input into a single TAB character with a code point of nine.

```
input = \t
input code points = [92, 116]
TAB code points = [9]
```

Answer (score 2):

You can utilize the [`StringEscapeUtils`](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringEscapeUtils.html) class from the [Apache Commons Text library](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/overview-summary.html) to achieve your goal, this way:

```java
String str = "\\t";
String unescapedStr = StringEscapeUtils.unescapeJava(str);
char c = unescapedStr.charAt(0);
```

The `StringEscapeUtils.unescapeJava` method converts escape sequences in a string to their corresponding characters. In this case, it will convert `\\t` to the tab character `'\t'`.

Remember to include the Apache Commons Text library in your project's dependencies!

But, if for some reason you don't want/can't use a library, you can do the `toChar` method this way:

```java
public static char toChar(String str) {
    switch (str) {
    case "\\t":
        return '\t';
    case "\\b":
        return '\b';
    case "\\n":
        return '\n';
    case "\\r":
        return '\r';
    case "\\f":
        return '\f';
    case "\\'":
        return '\'';
    case "\\\"":
        return '\"';
    case "\\\\":
        return '\\';
    default:
        throw new IllegalArgumentException();
    }
}
```

Comment: `StringEscapeUtils.unescapeJava` seems to do the job!

Comment: No need to add a library. This functionality is now built into Java.

Answer (score 1):

The String class itself has a [translateEscapes](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html#translateEscapes()) method which does this:

```
String str = "\\t";
char c = str.translateEscapes().charAt(0);
```